# Rebuilding packages received via async connections with high latency and packet drop

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

Today I have the following programming hypothesis:

If I have a client server application that has an asynchronous socket transfer (with 8kb buffer) and a latency of 500+ms  and a packet drop of ~25% (TCP)

If I send messages (xml bases) strings over to the recipient it might occur that the message (split in multiple packages) gets dropped and resend later on the order in which it is received is incorrect. (packet order should be 1-7 ordered instead of shown in the picture)

[image]

Lets say the first message consists of packet 1 -> 3 and the second message consists of packet (4 to 7) how would one recreate such messages?

An answer like fix the network is not what I am looking for. I want to create a robust transfer layer that can handle such problems

Comment: Out-of-order receipt at application level is not possible in a TCP octet/byte stream.

Comment: 'I want to create a robust transfer layer that can handle such problems' - youi already have one - TCP.

Comment: If you are receiving bytes out-of-order in your application, then either you are sending them out-of-order or the network stack at one/both ends is hopelessly broken.

Comment: I am not sure you understand the situation Martin. When packets drop and others arrive before the resend of the dropped it can occur that the order the packages arrive in are incorrect. (I've seen this happen in my own application and thus unable to rebuild the message)

e.g. I receive the first packet (nr 1) the second one gets dropped (and i  receive nr 3) then after the resend i receive nr 2.

Comment: If the TCP implementation is not borken, that cannot happen at application level.  The TCP header metadata has a sequence number to prevent out-of-order delivery to the application layer.

Comment: Thats what I tought as well but at high latencies & drops it does happen. As far as i know the TCP implementation is not broken. (how can i check such a thing anyways?)

Comment: If it happens, the stack is broken or the application is.  Are you, by any chance, using some sort of IOCP with multiple handler threads?

Comment: I am not using any form of IOCP. Just the plain C# socket that utilizes an async connection. So in short if the read callback is triggered then i read the amount of bytes on the socket. And keep on reading to fill a messagebuffer that gets parsed later on.

Comment: ..then you should be OK.  Why not cut the problem in half and wireshark the line to see if it's been sent in the correct order?

Comment: Good tip i'll try that any feedback will be posted :)

Comment: As Martin has said, the symptoms you describe are simply not possible with a correct TCP implementation. And it's highly doubtful you're using a TCP implementation that could be broken enough to do this. It is practically certain that you are either misinterpreting your observation, or that you have bug in your own code. If you want an answer here, you have to post [a good, _concise_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: The problem is tackled. It originated in my own code but seemed it was originating from the packets received. question closed... :)